# Java my program's array is not showing any values

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I'm writing a program to search for a string and tell me were it was found.

```
import java.io.*;


public class BinarySearchTest
{
   public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
   {
      int result;
      String searchValue;
      String input;

      // An array of numbers to search.
      String[] numbers = {"Jake", "Jerry", "Bill", "Lousie", "Goku", "Ivan", "John", "sarah", "kim"};

      // Create the console input objects.
      InputStreamReader reader =
                 new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      BufferedReader keyboard =
                 new BufferedReader(reader);

      // First we must sort the array in ascending order.
      IntQuickSorter.quickSort(numbers);

      do
      {
         // Get a value to search for.
         System.out.print("Enter a value to search for: ");
         input = keyboard.readLine();
         searchValue = input;

         // Search for the value
         result = IntBinarySearcher.i;

        // Display the results.
        if (result == -1)
           System.out.println(searchValue + " was not found.");
        else
        {
           System.out.println(searchValue + " was found at " +
                              "element " + result);
        }

        // Does the user want to search again?
        System.out.print("Do you want to search again? (Y or N): ");
        input = keyboard.readLine();
      } while (input.charAt(0) == 'y' || input.charAt(0) == 'Y');
   }
}




public class IntBinarySearcher
{
   static int i;





   public static int search(String[] numbers, String value)
   {
      int first;       // First array element
      int last;        // Last array element
      int middle;      // Mid point of search
      int position;    // Position of search value
      boolean found;   // Flag     

      // Set the initial values.
      first = 0;
      last = numbers.length - 1;
      position = -1;
      found = false;

      setI(Integer.parseInt(value));

      // Search for the value.
      while (!found && first <= last)
      {
         // Calculate mid point
         middle = (first + last) / 2;

         // If value is found at midpoint...
         if (numbers[middle].equals(value))
         {
            found = true;
            position = middle;
         }

         // else if value is in lower half...
         // need tell is value is less then the integer?, with out using equality regulators
         else if (value.compareTo(numbers[middle]) < 0)
            last = middle - 1;
         // else if value is in upper half....
         else
            first = middle + 1;
      }

      // Return the position of the item, or -1
      // if it was not found.
      return position;
   }

    public static void setI(int i) 
    {
        IntBinarySearcher.i = i;
    }

    public static int getI() 
    {
        return i;
    }
}






public class IntQuickSorter
{


   public static void quickSort(String[] numbers)
   {
      doQuickSort(numbers, 0, numbers.length - 1);
   }



   private static void doQuickSort(String[] numbers, int start, int end)
   {
      int pivotPoint;

      if (start < end)
      {
         // Get the pivot point.
         pivotPoint = partition(numbers, start, end);

         // Sort the first sub list.
         doQuickSort(numbers, start, pivotPoint - 1);

         // Sort the second sub list.
         doQuickSort(numbers, pivotPoint + 1, end);
      }
   }



   private static int partition(String[] numbers, int start, int end)
   {
      String pivotValue;    // To hold the pivot value
      int endOfLeftList; // Last element in the left sub list.
      int mid;           // To hold the mid-point subscript

      // Find the subscript of the middle element.
      // This will be our pivot value.
      mid = (start + end) / 2;

      // Swap the middle element with the first element.
      // This moves the pivot value to the start of 
      // the list.
      swap(numbers, start, mid);

      // Save the pivot value for comparisons.
      pivotValue = numbers[start];

      // For now, the end of the left sub list is
      // the first element.
      endOfLeftList = start;

      // Scan the entire list and move any values that
      // are less than the pivot value to the left
      // sub list.
      for (int scan = start + 1; scan <= end; scan++)
      {
         if (pivotValue.compareTo(numbers[scan])< 0) // pivotValue.compareTo(numbers[scan])< 0)
         {
            endOfLeftList++;
            swap(numbers, endOfLeftList, scan);
         }
      }

      // Move the pivot value to end of the
      // left sub list.
      swap(numbers, start, endOfLeftList);

      // Return the subscript of the pivot value.
      return endOfLeftList;
   }

   /**
      The swap method swaps the contents of two elements
      in an int array.
      @param The array containing the two elements.
      @param a The subscript of the first element.
      @param b The subscript of the second element.
   */

   private static void swap(String[] numbers, int a, int b)
   {
      String temp;

      temp = numbers[a];
      numbers[a] = numbers[b];
      numbers[b] = temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: If enter bill for example, Enter a value to search for: Bill
Bill was found at element 0.

Comment: So what is your question? If you have any error, please state exactly the error message. If you have incorrect output, please describe the expected and the actual output. The example you gave sounds correct: "Bill" should be the first element in the array after it is sorted.

Comment: That's quite a large amount of code, and not much description of where you suspect the problem to be.  It may help to pare this down to a short (maybe 10 lines) example, which should be straightforward for a relatively simple problem and may even lead to you solving your own problem!  See [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: In what way are "Jake", "Jerry" and "Bill" numbers? And in what way is accessing a static field "searching" for the value?

Comment: It not a error, my program says what ever a user enters is at element 0. My program is not finding match my string input to element location.

Comment: I also find it very confusing that your array of Strings is referred to as `numbers`, *everywhere*, when it's not numbers at all...

Comment: Isn't [this you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321378/my-array-gets-a-null-pointer-exception)? Why don't you continue posting as the same user?

Comment: "my program says what ever a user enters is at element 0." This is because `IntBinarySearcher.i` is initialized to 0 and never changed (`setI(int)` is never called and the only call that might get executed would throw an Exception, see my answer)

Comment: Bill is not a number. Why do you call them numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's something missing:

```
searchValue = input;

//IntBinarySearcher.search(numbers, searchValue); here?

// Search for the value
result = IntBinarySearcher.i;
```

Edit:

This won't work either since `IntBinarySearcher.i` is never "correctly" set (see Edit2) :).

Better:

```
result = IntBinarySearcher.search(numbers, searchValue);
```

Edit 2:

Oh, and this would throw a NumberFormatException for value="Bill": `setI(Integer.parseInt(value));`

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to be performing the search. You need the line:

```
IntBinarySearcher.search(numbers, searchValue);
```

before the line:

```
result = IntBinarySearcher.i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `IntQuickSorter.search()` anywhere. Call it after

```
searchValue = input;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your code where you're making a call to IntBinarySearcher.search. Without that i won't be set to anything, right?